# preventDefault not working on <a> inside a <div>

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I have this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.UIDropDown').click(function () {

        $('.button', this).click(function(e){ e.preventDefault()});

        $(this).addClass('active');


    });

});
```

And the following html:

```
<div class="UIDropDown">

    <a href="" class="button">button link</a>

    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Why is the e.preventDefault() not working on the .button? The page still refreshes .

Thx,

Comment: i think its better to do "<a href="javascript: void(0)">I am a useless link</a>" if you want to disable click event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you bind the event handler *after* the event has actually ocurred, and it doesn't get executed. Bind the event handler to the element in the DOM ready event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind event handler to the button
    $('.UIDropDown .button').click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
    // Bind event handler to the div (click on .button will trigger both)
    $('.UIDropDown').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/mgmy7/).

Answer (score 0):

try "return false;" instead of preventDefault(); That will block to going to URI. As in:

```
$('.button', this).click(function(e){ return false; });
```

Comment: `preventDefault` will work just fine if the event binding happens in the right place. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that link click function inside the div click function.

try this?

```
$('.UIDropDown').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('.button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
});​
```

​

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
  $('.UIDropDown').click(function () {

    $('.button', this).click(function(e){ return false; });

    $(this).addClass('active');


  });
```

Comment: That won't make any difference. `preventDefault` will work fine if the event binding happens in the right place. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should write

```
 $('.button').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault()});
```

outside the `click` handler of the `$('.UIDropDown')`

Comment: You probably don't want the `this` context argument when you move the `.button` event binding outside of the other event handler.